# Protractor Clicking Button In Angular JS

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, protractor

I am automating a site in protractor. I have done some coding and now have to click button but when I wrote button click code there is an Error
 more than one element found for locator by.partialButtonText("शोधा") - the first result will be used.

```
describe('angularjs homepage', function() {
it('should greet the named user', function() {
browser.get('https://mahabhulekh.maharashtra.gov.in/');
element(by.partialLinkText('अमरावती')).click();
browser.sleep('5000');
element(by.model("distCode")).$('[value="string:4"]').click();
browser.sleep('5000');
element(by.model("talCode")).$('[value="number:7"]').click();
browser.sleep('5000');
element(by.model("vilCode")).$('[value="string:270400070038950000"]').click
();
browser.sleep('5000');
element(by.id('rbsryno')).click();
browser.sleep('5000');
element(by.model("sno")).sendKeys("10");
browser.sleep('5000');
element(by.partialButtonText('शोधा')).click();
browser.sleep('5000');
});
});
```

Comment: you clearly have more than one button that matches the search criteria

Comment: Yes but then how to click the second one?

Comment: you will have to limit the buttons that match by making the criteria stricter

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get rid of message is changing:

`element(by.partialButtonText('शोधा')).click();`

to:

`element.all(by.partialButtonText('शोधा')).first().click();`

Comment: actually when we select different radio buttons different button loads but have same text. So what to do? As I have to choose the second one.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer

element.all(by.partialButtonText('शोधा')).get(1).click();